# How to assign ruby variable to javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select list and its javascript function in my views.

```
<select class="sel_list_size" id="product", onchange="build_url('dynamic_div')">
    <%= options_for_select(get_product) %>
</select>

function build_url(div_var) {
    var selected_index = product.selectedIndex;
    var selected_value = product.options[product.selectedIndex].text;
    var selSpan = document.createElement('span');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/welcome/get_inner_dirs',
      type: 'GET',
      data: { value: selected_value }
    });
}
```

and this is my controller method.

```
def get_inner_dirs
    cmd = `curl #{@url}/#{params[:value]}/`
    result = JSON.parse(cmd)
    @inner_dirs = []
    result.map { |e| @inner_dirs.append(e['name']) }
    @inner_dirs
end
```

So my aim is to create a dynamic select list using the data from `@inner_dirs`. Is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired result? As is its quite difficult to understand what you´re actually trying to accomplish. It usually helps if you can explain what you´re trying to do from a user story standpoint instead of the implementation details.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to pass data from Ruby to js. You can use data attributes to attach arbitrary data to DOM nodes. You can use `<script>window.x = <%= something.to_json %>;</script>` to inject a global.

Comment: Can also use https://github.com/gazay/gon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question since i found the solution.
I modified my controller method to return the json response.

```
def get_inner_dirs
    @inner_dirs = []
    cmd = `curl #{@url}/#{params[:value]}/`
    result = JSON.parse(cmd)
    result.map { |e| @inner_dirs.append(e['name']) }
    render :json => @inner_dirs
end
```

Any my javascript to render dynamic select list is (Gave comments inside the code on how i achieved that)

```
function build_url(div_var) {
    var selected_value = product.options[product.selectedIndex].text;
    var selSpan = document.createElement('span');
    var MyTestData = '';
    // call the controller method using ajax. When the call succeeded 
    // assign the JSON response to a javascript variable (MyTestData) 
    function ajax() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/welcome/get_inner_dirs',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { value: selected_value },
            success: function(data){ MyTestData = data }
        });
    }
    // Ajax call will be done here.
    ajax().done(function() {
        // Temp variable to build a select list
        var selectHTML = '';
        selectHTML = "<select>";
        selectHTML += '<option></option>'
        // Use the Ajax response to add options inside the select list
        for (i = 0; i < MyTestData.length; i = i + 1) {
            selectHTML += '<option>' + MyTestData[i] + "</option>"
        }
        selectHTML += "</select>";
        // Creating HTML for select list is completed now we need to 
        // insert the HTML inside a div or span
        selSpan.innerHTML = selectHTML;
        // So this div_var will be a HTML Element id where we need to 
        // push the select list
        document.getElementById(div_var).appendChild(selSpan);
      }).fail(function(){
          alert('Ajax call Failed')
    });
 }
```

So here is how i used the javascript in my HTML

```
<select class="sel_list_size" id="product" onchange="build_url('dynamic_div')">
    <%= options_for_select(get_product) %>
</select>
<div id='dynamic_div'></div>
```

I have an empty div below the select list in which the dynamic select list will be pushed when we select some value using the first select list